# Unable to load DLL 'amqxcs2.dll': The specified module could not be found. Works in Visual Studio but not IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, websphere

The asp.net website calls IBM MQ Queue and works correctly in Visual Studio 2010.  I deployed the website on IIS and it failed during browsing.  When I browse the website in IIS, I get the following error message:

Unable to load DLL 'amqxcs2.dll': The specified module could not be found

1. I have added the IBM Websphere bin directory to the PATH variable
2. I have copied all of the required DLLs in the bin directory and in GAC
3. I have given Ananoymous access to the folder which contains the DLLs

Please advice what I should do to resolve this error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved issue by setting LoadProfile = True in IIS App Pool settings
Also I am using ApplicationPoolIdentity as the account and enabled ASp.Net Impersonation and Windows Authentication.

Comment: Most important thing for me was the problem to get resolved. thank you for sharing solution.